# JPA - Returning updated Columns

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I would say it is a quite common use case. Giving some data in a table and a job (could also multiple parallel running jobs) which is fetching those data that are not yet processed. In order to achieve this, the following should happen:

- read rows with a given state (e.g. `is_processed = false`)
- lock the rows as long as they are not yet updated in order to avoid parallel processing of the same data (e.g. set `is_processed = true`)
- do something with the locked data
- update processed data (e.g. set `processed = true`)

With Postgres locking is a quite easy SQL command:

```
update <columen> set <key> = <value> returning *;
```

I would like to do exactly the same with JPA, but I don´t know how to achieve this.
In case it is important, I am running a Spring Boot application.

Comment: Use Versioning on your entity. For enabling optimistic locking

Comment: How could this solve the problem? At the end, I have the same problem, haven´t I? I have to 
1) read data
2) update the version number and
3) return the updated data.
And between 1 and 2 I have to make sure, that no other job fetched the data.

Comment: I believe you want to create native query using RETURNING keyword with JPA

Comment: @Modifying
@Query(value = "update <column> set <key> = <value> returning *", 
  nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> updateAll (String value);

Comment: good resource - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: @EdwinM.Cruz Using the nativeQuery is exactly doing what I am looking for. Thanks a lot. But how can this work, if another store than PostgreSQL will be used, for example an H2 for local testing. Since this is a native query, the tests will fail, right?